# Are these two graphs touching or intersecting?

Tags: calculus, slope

Do the curves $x^2 - 1$ and $2^x$ touch or intersect at $x=3$? Both have same values ($=8$) but values of their derivatives at $x=3$ are different. If two curves touch shouldn't their tangents have same slopes? Online graph calculators show the two curves as touching.

Comment: Desmos shows a second intersection at $x=3.407...$, and the derivatives aren't exactly equal.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: The precision of graphic calculators is usually quite limited.

Answer (score 1):

> the curves $x^2 - 1$ and $2^x$
>
> Online graph calculators show the two curves as touching.

[image]

If you zoom in sufficiently, their non-tangency becomes more apparent: the red and blue curves switch places.

> values of their derivatives at $x=3$ are different. If two curves touch shouldn't their tangents have same slopes?

Indeed, two ‘touching’ curves have the same slope at their point of contact.

Answer (score 0):

Evaluate derivatives at $x=3\;$; they are not equal.  They are not touching, ( although they seem to) but they intersect.

Somewhere else at about $x=2.2451$ the two curves have parallel tangents.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Here is the difference: $x^2-1-2^x$

[image]